# Extract a value from a URL fragment

Tags: c#, oauth, twitch

I'm using `HttpListener` to request an OAuth token from the Twitch.tv API. However, the API redict me to this url and the token as part of this URL fragment (as below) rather than as a parameter.

```
https://127.0.0.1/#access_token=<token>&scope=channel_editor
```

I've tried using the `RawUrl` property, but I'm not sure of the best way to extract the token from the URL fragment. Is there a recommended way of doing this in C#?

Comment: The `URI` class has a `Fragment` property.

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://domain.test/Default.aspx
var1=true&var2=test&var3=3");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
var var2 = query.Get("var2");
//You get the value "test"
```

Regards